# How to create mass credit memos magento 2?

Tags: magento2, module, sales, creditmemo, massaction

Total noob in magento here.

What I want is to select a bunch of orders, and **create credit memos** for them if their status is completed, and after the creditmemo is created, I want to set their statuses to `Refunded/Cancelled`, based on the payment method used.

Any tips on how I should go about the whole process?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I have created an action in the sales_order_grid.xml as follows:

```
<action name="masscreditmemos_order">
        <settings>
                <url path="sales/order/masscreditmemos"/>
                <type>masscreditmemos_order</type>
                <label translate="true">Generate Credit Memos</label>
        </settings>
</action>
```

Then created a file named "masscreditmemos.php" in

> module_sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/

with the following content:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory;

class masscreditmemos extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\AbstractMassAction
{
    /**
     * Authorization level of a basic admin session
     */
    const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Magento_Sales::creditmemo';

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Filter $filter
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     */


public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\CreditmemoFactory $creditmemoFactory,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice $invoice,
    CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\CreditmemoService $creditmemoService,
    array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($data);
        $this->order = $order;
        $this->creditmemoFactory = $creditmemoFactory;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->creditmemoService = $creditmemoService;
        $this->invoice = $invoice; 
    }

public function massAction(AbstractCollection $collection)
{
    $order = $this->order;
    $order->load(10);

    $invoices = $order->getInvoiceCollection();
    foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
        $invoiceincrementid = $invoice->getIncrementId();
    }

    $invoiceobj = $this->invoice->loadByIncrementId($invoiceincrementid);
    $creditmemo = $this->creditmemoFactory->createByOrder($order);

    // Don't set invoice if you want to do offline refund
    $creditmemo->setInvoice($invoiceobj);

    $this->creditmemoService->refund($creditmemo); 
}
}
```

But when I click the on the "generate credit memo" action, it shows me a 500 error. The error is as follows:

[image: php_error.log]

What am I doing wrong?

Also. I know I am supposed to override the vendor modules, I will do that once this runs.

Comment: You need to create custom extenison and into which add new action for order grid and perform the logic part into that action.

Comment: @dhirenVasoya Hi. I was able to make a custom module which added a section called "Generate Credit Memos" in the action drop down. but have some trouble formulating the logic behind the whole operation. I mean, traditionally, when we view an order, and if it's status is "completed/processing" a button for creating a credit memo is shown, which redirects to a form and creates a memo for the record, and changes the status to "closed".

Not sure how i'll override the form and do a mass action of generating credit memos.

Comment: you need to create credit memo or order programetically into your above action.

Comment: Let me try that

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Please check my edit.